# javascript/jquery remove or delete option from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to delete an option from a select in certain circumstances.

Basically:

```
if(mystatement == true)
{
   //remove item with id 'option1' from select of id 'select1'
}
```

Anyone know the code for me to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Edit***

Since id is unique in the document no need to relate it to the parent select element. You can do simply

```
$("#option1").remove();
```

Answer (score 13):

Remove by Value:

```
$("#select1 option[value=1]").remove();
```

Remove by Text:

```
$("#select1 option:contains(Text)").remove();
```

Comment: For text, `contains` seems like a bad idea, no? Any reason why not to use `$("#select1 option:[text='My Text']")` ?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$("#option1").remove();
```

or

```
$("#select").remove("#option1");
```

And the classic javascript method:

```
var option1 = document.getElementById("option1");
document.getElementById("select1").removeChild(option1);
```

Comment: `$("#select1")` is unnecessary. `$("#option1").remove()` will suffice since it is matched by `id`.

Comment: @Marko: I was editing that in as you posted your comment :-) I left the original in as adding IDs to option tags is fairly uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many people with this problem. I have created this script that could be useful. Hope you like it:

```js
var robable = {
  init: function() {
    robable.get_selected_option_from_select();
  },
  get_selected_option_from_select: function() {
    $(".robable").off().on("change", function() {
      if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        robable.add_to_list($(this));
      }
    });
  },
  remove_option_from_select: function(select_id, value) {
    $("#" + select_id + " option[value='" + value + "']").remove();
  },
  add_option_to_select: function(select_id, value, text) {
    $('#' + select_id).append('<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>');
  },
  add_to_list: function(select) {

    option_text = $(".robable option[value='" + select.val() + "']").text();

    //Add to list
    $('#list').append("<li data-value='" + select.val() + "' data-text='" + option_text + "'><a href='#' class='filter-remove' data-parent-id='" + select.attr("id") + "'>Delete</a> " + option_text + "</li>");
    robable.remove_from_list();

    //Remove from select
    robable.remove_option_from_select(select.attr("id"), select.val());
  },
  remove_from_list: function() {
    $(".filter-remove").off().on("click", function() {
      var select_id = $(this).data('parent-id');
      var option_value = $(this).closest("li").data('value');
      var option_text = $(this).closest("li").data('text');

      //Add to select
      robable.add_option_to_select(select_id, option_value, option_text);

      //Remove from list
      $(this).closest("li").remove();
    });
  }
};

robable.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Select Robables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <ul id="list"></ul>

</body>

</html>
```