# Deleting a an element in an array of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I have an array `$('#data')` and I know what element I need to delete.
The element I need to delete is `$('#data')[0][2]`

`$('#data')[0]` is:

```
<select id="data" class="classOne" name="data">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

making `$('#data')[0][2]` (the element I need to delete) `<option value="option2">option2</option>`

I've tried using `.pop()` and `delete $('#data')[0][2]` and both of these don't work. How can I remove that element?

Comment: Did you check this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424468/javascript-jquery-remove-or-delete-option-from-select It looks extremely similar to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use an adequate selector, for example using the [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class and the [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) `JQuery` method to remove the element:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#data option:nth-child(2)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="data" class="classOne" name="data">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Or, without `JQuery`:

```js
document.querySelector("#data option:nth-child(2)").remove();
```

```html
<select id="data" class="classOne" name="data">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```js
$('#data option').get(1).remove() // index 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="data" class="classOne" name="data">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```